# array_chunk'ing a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I have a multi-dimensional array and I am looking to split it up every 10 elements.

`array_chunk` appeared to be the solution, but I can't find anything that suggests it supports multi-dimensional arrays.

Is this possible using PHP 5.3?

This is a sample of my current array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cart Object
        (
            [cartId:protected] => 4337032
            [userId:protected] => 271561
            [orderId:protected] => 1042104
        )
    [1] => Cart Object
        (
            [cartId:protected] => 4337032
            [userId:protected] => 271561
            [orderId:protected] => 1042104
        )
    ... and so on ...
)
```

What i'm looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
          Array (
                 [0] => Cart Object
                 (
                    [cartId:protected] => 4337032
                    [userId:protected] => 271561
                    [orderId:protected] => 1042104
                 )
                 [1] => Cart Object
                 (
                    [cartId:protected] => 4337032
                    [userId:protected] => 271561
                    [orderId:protected] => 1042104
                )
    [1] => // the next 10...
)
```

Comment: Can you show us how the array looks like? And what you want as result? Also, why not just loop with step range 10 and create new array?

Comment: Show an example of what you want and what you've got

Comment: did u mean to split the array every 10 elements in the first dimension or "count" to 10 while looping through all dimensions and split it on there position(s)?

Comment: @MarkBaker Sample array provided.

Comment: Well I would just write my own function dumping the items in a new array, not sure if what you want works for array_chunck @MarkBaker?

Comment: Based on what you've posted, array_chunk() should work without problem.... you don't have a multidimensional array, you simply have an array of objects

Comment: @MarkBaker I cut down the array for the benefit of not copy-pasting a big structure into the question. However, you are right `array_chunk` does indeed work. I misread the documentation and didn't realise it returned the array rather than just changing it. Thanks, feel free to submit an answer as I will gladly accept as you did point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$carts_to_page = array_chunk($carts, 10);`